# Using automated whatsapp to send image

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to send image by whtasapp by using automated python script. But it only sending the image to last phone number which i provvide in the list. I used the code to send message to the same list of number and its working. I don't know where I'm going wrong. Can anyone help me in this ?

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import socket
import getpass
import os


user = getpass.getuser()
# print(user)
# os.system("pause")




filepath = input('Enter your filepath (images/video): ')
no_of_message=1
moblie_no_list=[919523050695,918679434243]

def element_presence(by,xpath,time):
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
    WebDriverWait(driver, time).until(element_present)

def is_connected():
    try:
        # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually
        # reachable
        socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
        return True
    except :
        is_connected()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/kesood/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://web.whatsapp.com")
sleep(10) #wait time to scan the code in second

def send_whatsapp_msg(phone_no,image):
    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={}&source=&data=#".format(phone_no))
    try:
        driver.switch_to.alert()
    except Exception as e:
        pass

    try:
        element_presence(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]',30)
        attachment_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@title = "Attach"]')
        attachment_box.click()
        image_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//input[@accept="image/*,video/mp4,video/3gpp,video/quicktime"]')
        image_box.send_keys(filepath)
        sleep(3)
        send_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-icon="send"]')
        send_button.click()
        global no_of_message
        for x in range(no_of_message):

            send_button.send_keys(image)
            send_button.send_keys("\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Telefone Invalido:"+str(phone_no))
for moblie_no in moblie_no_list:
    try:
        send_whatsapp_msg(moblie_no,filepath)

    except Exception as e:
        sleep(10)
        is_connected()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Send files takes a little time to load. Before the image totally load to the first contact chat, the program try the url to send message to the second before loading, then its interrupted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).